# Retrieving and Displaying tweets into an Windows 8 metro application

Tags: twitter, windows-8, microsoft-metro, blend

so basically I'm trying to display the latest tweets from 5-10 different sources/twitter accounts in a new application I'm trying to make.

Similarly the way tweetro/metrotwit retrieve and display tweets in the application. But on a much smaller scale.

Any ideas on how this could be done?

Would be much appreciated.

Duncan

Comment: This question is much too broad.  Try finding a specific portion of it and asking a question about that.

Comment: Well I just want to find out out I can embed user tweets into an application? You have any idea on what I need to be targeting my research towards?

Comment: Are you having trouble retrieving the tweets?  Displaying them?  What language?

Comment: No no, I'm trying to create an application that displays the latest tweets from a pre-defined set of users, maybe 4-5 accounts.

Comment: But what part don't you know how to do?

Comment: Just how do I tell visual studio/blend to look for tweets from certain accounts from twitter and display them in a list/grid on a new store application

Comment: You're basically asking someone to code it for you.  To fit the site better you need to come up with a more specific question.  Barring that, here is a package that already does twitter stuff: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/TwitterRt-Tweet-from-9ccfac7e#content

Comment: Alex, your question is too broad. Start small. Get familiar with [Twitter's API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs). Look into API libraries for C#, if you like ([here's one](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp)). That last site looks like it has a decent tutorial for you to walk through.

Comment: Thanks for the links guys, I'll have a look! -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/) to send a Web Service Request accessing those specific tweets in a data friendly format like XML or text.  Then simply bind that data to a ListView or whatever pleases you.